# Shell Script no output in finding remainder

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal

```
echo "Enter the number"
read $num

echo "number in reverse order is : "

ten=10

while [[ $num -gt 0 ]];
 do
    echo $((num%ten))
   
    num=`expr $num / 10`
done
```

I'm running this on mac terminal
nothing is printing or echoing on terminal. Question to print a number in reverse order .
Please help my I'm fed of this, and if any one can suggest me some good content on this than I will be grateful.

Comment: You should consider using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to resolve certain issues before you post ... hint:  `read $num` won't work, you don't use `$` in assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Smells a little bit like homework, anyway - here we go:

```
for ((i=${#num}-1; i>=0; i--))
   do printf "%s" ${num:$i:1}
   done
echo ""
```

This solution also works for non-numbers